# Get a list (and count) of bugs raised per Iteration in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'd like to be able to get a list with the bugs raised during a Sprint against any of the PBIs in that Sprint. Is there a way to achieve that? We are currently using TFS 2015 with its Scrum template.

So far I've managed to run a custom query in which I retrieve all the work items with the following criteria:

- Work Item Type = Bug.
- Iteration Path = *Path to the specific Iteration*
- Created Date >= *Start date of the Iteration*
- Created Date <= *End date of the Iteration*

However, this approach is far from ideal, given that I need to hardcode the dates, and if I want to compare how we've been doing Iteration after Iteration in terms of bugs raised, I need to create several queries and manually update them.

Can you think of a better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not able to do this based on a single query, try to do this through API. You can query for bugs, tasks, other types of work items, and links between work items by using one of the `WorkItemStore.Query` methods or a Query object.

You could use WIQL to do this.  According to this tutorial [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306.aspx),  use the `Under` comparison operator in your query. A sample to pull all work items in an Iteration,

```
select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State]
from WorkItems
where
  [System.TeamProject] = 'VieroSAT'
  and [System.State] = 'Dev'
  and [System.IterationPath] Under 'Iteration1'
order by [System.Id]
```

You could also import all bugs /PBIs for each iteration including the created data info to a Excel List. With the help of powerful Excel tool to filter and generate chart or tables you need.